TypeScript Error: "Return type of exported function has or is using name 'LoaderSlotProps' from external module" in Vuetify Drawer Component
I’m encountering the following TypeScript error in my Vue 3 + Vuetify project:
Return type of exported function has or is using name 'LoaderSlotProps' from external module "node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/index" but cannot be named.  


Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
Added "skipLibCheck": true in my tsconfig.json.
Checked the Vuetify documentation to ensure I’m using slots correctly.
Updated Vuetify and TypeScript to the latest versions.
Additional Context:
Vue version: 3.2.x
Vuetify version: 3.x
TypeScript version: 5.x
Build Tool: Vite
It seems like the issue is related to the LoaderSlotProps type from Vuetify. Do I need to manually define this type or is there a better solution to resolve this?
